# Sharepoint package installation - Feature is not visible in Site collection -> settings

Tags: workflow, feature, designer-workflow, solution-package, feature-activation

I am not very experienced with Sharepoint 2010 and I am having trouble installing a package.

I downloaded a package from "iLove SharePoint" as I need to call web service from a workflow. The package I downloaded is  "Workflow Actions for SharePoint Designer 2010"

When I am installing it according to instructions of the package. It gets installed fine and when i goto "Manage Web Applications" and select my Web app "http:// [mywebapp:80]" - click Manage Features -- I can see the package their and it shows up as "ACTIVATED"

However, I cannot find the features when i goto Site Setings -> Manage Site Features ?? - What am I doing wrong here?

I am trying to call a web service when a workflow starts and this package seems to add that as an action to workflow. Anyone can give out some suggestions please?

Thanks,

Instruction set of installing this package.

http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Install%20Workflow%20Actions%20for%20SharePoint%20Designer%202010&referringTitle=Workflow%20Actions%20for%20SharePoint%20Designer%202010

Answer (score 1):

The Key is in #6 of the instructions.

"Activate the site collection feature "iLove SharePoint - SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflow Actions" in the site settings of site collections where you want to use the actions. The Web Application Feature must be activated for the Web Application of the Site Collection. 
"

It's a Site collection feature and not a Site Feature!

Answer (score 0):

Did you look under the Site Collection Features? It will be located under the Site Collection Administration heading.  If this is a subsite, you will need to navigate up to the root site--this can be done easily by clicking on the 'Go to top level site settings'.